# Transferring values from multiple columns in a dataframe to a new column in another dataframe, based on time-criterion

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty new to Python, and start to realize its potential for serious number-crunching.

Presently, I wish to create a new column in a pandas dataframe (df1) and populate it with the numeric value from one of 24 columns (named `0.0`-`23.0`) in another dataframe (df2). Each of columns `0.0`-`23.0` represents hours (`00.00-00.59`, `01.00-01.59` and so on). I want to perform my operation based on a time criterion.

There is a column `time` in df1, with a datetime value in the format `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS`. This column is not the index column of df1, so several rows may have the same value of 'time'. df1 contains a total of 300,000 rows.

The index of df2 is a column `date` which contains values in the form `YYYY-mm-dd`. df2 covers 3 years and hence contains a total of about 1,200 rows.

For example, if the value of `time` in df1 is `2011-01-01 12:01:20`, I want to populate the new column in df1 with the numeric value from column `12.0` in df2, corresponding to the row with index `2011-01-01`.

I have tried to merge the two dataframes and obtained a new dataframe containing df1 and the columns `0.0`-`23.0` matched to the correct date. I did this by converting 'time' to the `YYYY-mm-dd` format and applying .merge. However, this dataframe is a bit too messy.

Furthermore, I would like to write a function evaluating the new column in df1, to allow for a backward control that the imported values from df2 are correct.

df1

```
KEY    time
252752 2011-01-01 04:20:00   
281789 2011-01-02 01:18:00   
242674 2011-01-03 03:08:00   
189497 2011-01-04 00:17:00   
189498 2011-01-05 05:31:00   
...    ...
```

df2

```
date         0.0         1.0         2.0         3.0         4.0         5.0        ...   23.0
2011-01-01   0.919355    0.925806    0.929032    0.932258    0.938710    0.953947   ...   1.037975
2011-01-02   1.026144    1.019608    1.022876    1.032680    1.035948    1.035948   ...   0.919355
2011-01-03   1.025316    1.034810    1.037975    1.034810    1.044304    1.044304   ...   1.018987
2011-01-04   1.018987    1.025316    1.031646    1.044304    1.047468    1.050633   ...   0.932258
2011-01-05   1.018987    1.018987    1.018987    1.022152    1.031646    1.037975   ...   0.953947
...          ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...        ...   ...
```

desired result

```
KEY    time                  value
252752 2011-01-01 04:20:00   0.938710
281789 2011-01-02 01:18:00   1.019608
242674 2011-01-03 03:08:00   1.034810
189497 2011-01-04 00:17:00   1.018987
189498 2011-01-05 05:31:00   1.037975
...    ...                   ...
```

Comment: It's conventional to post a short but sufficient copy-and-paste-able example of the input you have and the output you expect.  That way, no one has to spend time mocking up an example of his own.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if this helps... but thats the way i would write it:

```
 ### just to have your test data
    df1_val =     ("252752 2011-01-01 04:20:00",   
                    "281789 2011-01-02 01:18:00",   
                    "242674 2011-01-03 03:08:00",   
                    "189497 2011-01-04 00:17:00",   
                    "189498 2011-01-05 05:31:00") 
    df1 = {}
    for row in df1_val:
        df1[row[0:5]]= (row[7:17], row[18:])

    df2_val = ( "2011-01-01   0.919355    0.925806    0.929032    0.932258    0.938710    0.953947",
                "2011-01-02   1.026144    1.019608    1.022876    1.032680    1.035948    1.035948",
                "2011-01-03   1.025316    1.034810    1.037975    1.034810    1.044304    1.044304",
                "2011-01-04   1.018987    1.025316    1.031646    1.044304    1.047468    1.050633",
                "2011-01-05   1.018987    1.018987    1.018987    1.022152    1.031646    1.037975")

    df2 = {}
    for row in df2_val:
        date, zero, one, two, three, four, five = row.split("   ")
        df2[date] = (zero, one, two, three, four, five)

    #### build the result dict
    result = {}    

    for key in df1:
        hour =  int(df1[key][1][:2])
        date = df1[key][0]
        result[key] = (df1[key][0] + "   " + df1[key][1], df2[date][hour], )
        print key
        print result[key]
```

Comment: Maybe I'm a slow catcher, but I did not manage to transform this into a working solution.  1. Is "key" in your example referring to the "KEY" in df1? 2. What is to be written between the quotation signs in the fourth row of the last for-statement?

Comment: No not a slow catcher, i have my own style to think ;)
key is your id - ie. 252752 which is the key of both dictionarys. 
result = dictionary whith the id as key.
i think the +"    " +  isnt really neccessary its just to combine date and time in the same way the sample data is
so it goes through all the lines(key) of df1,
search for every key the coresponding line in df2 (via the date) 
add the value throug the column (col 1 = hour 1, col2 = hour 2,...)

Comment: this is the output

18949
('2011-01-05   05:31:00', ' 1.037975')
25275
('2011-01-01   04:20:00', ' 0.938710')
24267
('2011-01-03   03:08:00', ' 1.034810')
28178
('2011-01-02   01:18:00', ' 1.019608')

just saw you need df2[date][hour+1]